# Building an R package on Travis, how not to treat warnings as errors?

Tags: r, travis-ci

I'm [building an R package on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/paulrougieux/tradeflows/builds/109356597) to share the integration status with users of the package. I have no errors but 8 warnings and I would like to ignore them for the moment. But travis considered the build a failure and returns the message on the last line of the R CMD check log:

```
Found warnings, treating as errors (as requested)
```

How to ignore warnings?

Comment: Did the answer below address your problem?  If so, please accept it so the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: Yes adding `warnings_are_errors: false` to `.travis.yml` did address my problem. The Travis build wasn't finished before I went home yesterday evening. The build is passing now. I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All you need to do is have

```
warnings_are_errors: false
```

near the top of your `.travis.yml` file

Here is an [example](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/blob/develop/.travis.yml) from one of my R packages.