# How not to treat warnings as errors with Travis for React

Tags: reactjs, travis-ci

I'm developing an application with React, with Travis continuous integration system. When executing the process, Travis complains about warnings, and fails to compile because it indicates:

`Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.
Failed to compile.`

I tried to modify the .travis.yml file and add the rule `warnings_are_errors: false` as indicated in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412383/building-an-r-package-on-travis-how-not-to-treat-warnings-as-errors), but it simply ignores it and does not work.

Comment: Hey! Have you seen [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3657)?

Comment: Thanks @MaëlPedretti, but I think this doesn't work. The problem is that I don't know where to set that parameter 'CI=false', because in my package.json of the application the build script is set as '"build": "react-scripts build"'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I will post this solution in case anyone has the same issue. To solve it, I've just modified the rule of the build process in the `.travis.yml` file.

Finally, the result of that file is like this:

```
script:
  - npm install -g codecov
  - npm test && codecov
  - CI=false npm run build
  - npm run docs
```

With that option, Travis just recognizes the `CI=false` to allow the system not to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: More information about this can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3657

Comment: It seems the treatment given by create-react-app to the CI environment variable declares to stop if there are linter warning errors as described in the create-react-app documentation: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#continuous-integration

Comment: for some reason it say that "CI=false" is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, scriptable file, or operable program.